# Find the number of days ago a given java.util.Date object is from the current date

Tags: java, date

What's the most standard, performant way of figuring out how many days ago a particular java.util.Date object represents? Ideally, I want to get back a double representing the (potentially) fractional number of days ago.

Comment: How do you define "number of days ago"?  For example, lets say you go across a daylight savings time event.

Answer (score 5):

That sounds remarkably like:

```
(System.currentTimeMillis() - date.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000d);
```

In other words, find out the difference between the current time and the given date in millis, and then divide by the number of milliseconds in a day. I've explicitly made the 1000d a double literal to make the final division work in double arithmetic.

Comment: I haven't even finished reading the question, and there, you have the answer already. :)

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html), which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html), to find the duration between two instants. Also, avoid performing calculations yourself if you already have a standard API  to do the job.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A sample date-time in the past
        String strDateTime = "2020-09-10T10:20:30.123456789Z";

        Instant past = Instant.parse(strDateTime);
        Instant now = Instant.now();

        Duration duration = Duration.between(past, now);
        long durationInMillis = duration.toMillis();

        double days = (double) durationInMillis / Duration.ofDays(1).toMillis();
        System.out.println(days);
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
299.14329884259257
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/KpdOUv)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Indeed, that is simpler! Even though the number of function calls is the same, the original solution needed one more type. Updated the answer to incorporate it. Thanks, @OleV.V. for the valuable suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Get `System.currentTimeMillis()` and find Date from it. Then get `day`, `month`, `year`. Now it should be easy find difference.